# java garbage collection : reference to unreferenced object's member object

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose we have a class:

```
public class test{
    public String member;
    public test()
    {
        member = new String("internal object");
    }
};
```

If I wrote this :

```
String refToUnreferencedClassMember = new test().member;
```

Is this problematic? The unreferenced object `new test()` has no reference pointing to itself, but there is a reference pointing to it's member object `String member`. If the unreferenced object is garbage collected, then `refToUnreferencedClassMember` will be invalid.

Thanks for your help. I don't know whether garbage collection will take place in this situation.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be any problem performing this call. Even when the `new test()`-Object is garbage collected, the string shouldn't change because the value is copied (see: call by value vs. call by reference).
But I'm not pro, so someone should confim this.. .

Comment: No, `refToUnreferencedClassMember` will not be invalid. The object is referenced from both the new test() object and refToUnreferencedClassMember. When new test GC still the String object will be alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case,

```
new test().member;
```

will point to a `String` object in java heapspace.

Now when you assign it to

```
refToUnreferencedClassMember
```

then that `String` object would have two references i.e. one via *anonymous  `new test()` object* and another via *`refToUnreferencedClassMember`*.

Note that test object would be eligible for GC. And when the anonymous `new test()` object is GC'd, your string object would still have one reference left i.e. `refToUnreferencedClassMember`, thus not allowing it to be GC'd.

Comment: Note that the same happens with the `String` objects. The `String` instance representing the literal `"internal object"` and the instance created explicitly via `new String("internal object")` will both point to the same array containing the actual character contents. The array will persist as long as a reference to at least one of these two instances exists.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this problematic?

No.

> The unreferenced object new test() has no reference pointing to itself, but there is a reference pointing to its member object `String` member.

Correct.

> If the unreferenced object is garbage collected, then `refToUnreferencedClassMember` will be invalid.

No it won't, unless it is unreferenced. As it is referenced in your example, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

That field has no knowledge regarding that enclosing object.

Therefore that enclosing object is immediately eligible to be garbage collected.

That string stays until the reference to it goes away.

But please note: from the object oriented point of view, you really want to avoid exposing mutable fields of classes. Allowing other classes to manipulate the internal state of members is something to not do!