# Will a prototype bean which contains a singleton bean be garbage collected once it is used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, garbage-collection, spring-aop

```java
@Component
class ClassB {
    //Singleton class which is being used in classA
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("did something");
    }
}

@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class ClassA {
    //Prototype class which is being used in Main class

    @Autowired
    ClassB classb;

    public void methodA() {
        //do something
        classb.doSomething();
    }

}


@Component
class Main {
    
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void createAndUseClassA() {
        //Spring would create a new instance of classA
        var classA = applicationContext.getBean(ClassA.class);  
        //used class A
        classA.methodA();
        //after this method ends there would be no reference of classA
    }
}
```

In the above case the `Main` class is asking Spring to create an instance of a prototype bean (`ClassA`) which it uses inside `createAndUseClassA()` method. Now according to the Spring docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Spring does not keep any reference to the prototype bean after creation, but Spring does keep a reference to the singleton bean in the Spring context. So in this case, after the method `createAndUseClassA()` is finished, there would be no references to the object referenced by `classA`, but Spring context would have a reference to `ClassB`, which is inside the object `ClassA`. My question is would this stop the GC from collecting the instance of `ClassA` after execution of `createAndUseClassA()`?

Comment: `ClassB` instance have no reference to `ClassA` instance . Unreferenced `ClassA` instance will be eligibile for GC. Please go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51464029/4214241) and the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `ClassA` instance is not used elsewhere, it will be eligible for GC. Of course since `ClassB` is a singleton and it is managed by Spring, it this will not be collected. The fact that `classB` is alive does not present `classA` to be collected.

Btw your comment is a bit off :

```
//after this method ends there would be no reference of classA
```

You are confusing scope and reachability. Think about it this way, if there is *more* code after that comment (but it does not use `classA`) it can still be collected *before* the methods ends.